# Assigning values to Jenkins environment variables is not working

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I declared the environment variables in pipeline syntax and I'm trying to assign values to the variables by reading the file from workspace.  Assigned values are not reflected in environment variable. my configuration looks like below

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        
        test = ''
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
           script {
                  writeFile(file: 'hello.txt', text: "hello world")               
                   
                  env.test = readFile(file: 'hello.txt')
                  echo 'test:'"${env.test}" // coming as null          
               }
            }
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: That syntax is invalid and fails the declarative linter check. Please update the question for accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `test` from environment block.

Also, you have a problem with `''` and `""` when you display `env.test`, try to do this:

```
echo "test: ${env.test}" // coming as null
```